# Calling function from ComImport class doesn't fail as expected

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I'm trying to verify that the class I'm trying to use via COM works as expected. Unfortunately it seems to succeed on a call which should fail:

```
enum X509CertificateEnrollmentContext
{
    ContextUser = 0x1,
    ContextMachine = 0x2,
    ContextAdministratorForceMachine = 0x3
}

[ComImport(), Guid("884e2045-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09")]
class Cenroll { }

[Guid("728ab35d-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09")]
interface IX509CertificateRequestCmc2
{
    void InitializeFromTemplate(
        [In] X509CertificateEnrollmentContext Context,
        [In] IX509EnrollmentPolicyServer pPolicyServer,
        [In] IX509CertificateTemplate pTemplate);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cr = new Cenroll();
    var cmc2 = (IX509CertificateRequestCmc2)cr;
    cmc2.InitializeFromTemplate(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, null, null);
}
```

Casting from Cenroll to the interface works, which indicates that the guids are ok. (and it fails casting to other guids, so it's not random success)

But when I call `InitializeFromTemplate`, with both parameters set to `null`, it succeeds. The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/ee351621%28v=vs.85%29) says that the result should be an `E_POINTER` error:

```
Return code - Description
E_POINTER - The pPolicyServer and pTemplate parameters cannot be NULL.
```

So why don't I see an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are redeclaring the interface, and the new definition is different from the original.

Guids are OK, but underneath, `QueryInterface` implementation checks GUID, and returns the pointer to the implementation - this is the interface vtable and method addresses are calculated relative to this address (when a call to the method is compiled, offset of the method is added to this address to get the actuall address).

In your implementation, `InitializeFromTemplate` is the first method and generated client code calls the method at the beginning of vtable.

However, in the original interface, there are 56 other methods before `InitializeFromTemplate` because there is an inheritance chain:

```
IX509CertificateRequest (25 methods)
|
+-> IX509CertificateRequestPkcs7 (8 methods)
    |
    +-> IX509CertificateRequestCmc (23 methods)
        |
        +-> IX509CertificateRequestCmc2
```

Function addresses in the certenroll.dll adhere to this layout, so when you call `InitializeFromTemplate` as declared in your interface, you are calling the first method in chain which is actually `IX509CertificateRequest::Initialize`.

As an experiment, if you add 56 dummy methods before `InitializeFromTemplate` in your `IX509CertificateRequestCmc2` you will correctly receive an exception:

```
[Guid("728ab35d-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09")]
interface IX509CertificateRequestCmc
{
    void fn1();
    void fn2();
    ...
    void fn56();
    void InitializeFromTemplate(...);
}
```

The call will throw: `CertEnroll::CX509CertificateRequestCmc::InitializeFromTemplate: Invalid pointer 0x80004003 (-2147467261)`

Of course, the solution is not to add the dummy methods :) You should use the generated interop types instead of providing your own. As you are referencing the `certenroll` assembly, I don't understand why don't you simply use those generated interop classes. Here's the full example which behaves as expected:

```
using CERTENROLLLib;

namespace comcerttest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // If you are embedding the interop types, note that you must
            // remove the `Class` suffix from generated type name in order
            // to instantiate it. See link at the bottom for explanation:
            var cr = new CX509CertificateRequestCmc();
            var cmc2 = (IX509CertificateRequestCmc2)cr;
            cmc2.InitializeFromTemplate(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with using class vs interface type is explained here:
[Using embedded interop types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue! Why I didn't use generated interop classes: the documentation is so bad that it took me a few days to figure out I could. And that's after figuring out xenroll-vs-certenroll, COM usage, etc. </rant>

Comment: It can be daunting, that's true :)